# MockK calls actual method when using mockkConstructor

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I'm trying to mock the constructor of a class, and define some behaviour on the methods of the constructed object. I'm using `mockk` to do this, and following [their instructions](https://mockk.io/) to get it setup. However, I'm finding that when I try to define the mock behaviour, mockk is invoking the actual underlying method in the class, which fails because there are things missing on the mock.

Here's a minimal example

```kotlin
class TestConstructed() {
    fun justThrows(): Int {
        throw NotImplementedError()
    }
}

class MinimalExample {
    @Test
    fun testMockConstructor() {
        mockkConstructor(TestConstructed::class)
        every { anyConstructed<TestConstructed>().justThrows() } returns 42

        val constructed = TestConstructed()

        assertThat(constructed.justThrows()).isEqualTo(42)
    }
}
```

In the case above the call to `justThrows` inside `every` throws an exception, so the test never passes. What I want is to be able to mock the call to `justThrows` without the exception being thrown.

I'm using MockK 1.13.10 and running with JUnit 5.10.0

Thoughts?

Comment: For what it's worth, I seem to be seeing a similar behaviour when mocking top-level functions using `mockkStatic`

Comment: Also, downgrading to mockk and using the old version of mockkStatic, the one that receives a string, does seem to work. So there seems to be a problem with the implementation of `mockkStatic(::method)`, and a similar problem with `mockkConstructor`?

Comment: Using the `mockkStatic(String)` version in 1.13.10 seems to have the same problem. So the issue seems to be with version 1.13.10 overall

Comment: I tried running the code you posted in your question with the same versions of MockK + JUnit and it's working as expected. On a side note, why do you need to mock the constructor? If all you're actually mocking is `justThrows()`, you can just do this `val myInstance = mockk<TestConstructed>(); every { myInstance.justThrows() } returns 42`

Comment: @user2340612 thanks for looking into this. The actual code I'm testing is a class that provides an SDK-like interface over an HTTP client. Because of _reasons_, the class builds the HTTP client in its constructor, and then uses it in its methods. So what I'm trying to do is mock the constructor of the HTTP client, so that I can inject a mocked client and verify that downstream calls are done adequately.

Comment: I've downgraded mockk to 1.12.8, and things seem to be working fine on that version

Comment: I'm sure you have already considered it, but just in case you haven't: would it make sense to supply the HTTP client in the constructor (e.g. so that you can swap it later with another one if needed)?

Comment: @user2340612 yeah, I've pushed the constructor as far up the call stack as I could, and now I'm testing the entry point that actually needs to construct the object. This question is more about the testing of the code, rather than the structure.